# Pandas: Find if string in column have word from list and replace all string with word

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

my problem is:

I have list with colors

color_list = ['red', 'black', 'white', "a'pink", 'blue']

and a dataframe with column have complex strings

i need find if in the strings have color from my list and

1 replace all string with color from my list
2 add column with True if find and replace and False if dont find

Thank you!!

```
color_list = ['red', 'black', 'white', "a'pink", 'blue']
print(color_list)

import pandas as pd
data = ['on red', 'aup red gone', 'black with bi', "ao a' pink", 'dgfh blu', 'a black pen']

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['colors'])

# print dataframe.

print('my data frame is: ')
print(df)
print(30*"#")
print('i need the answer be but i dont know how put regex for strings from list: ')

data_2 = [['red','True'], ['red','True'], ['black','True'], ["a' pink",'True'] ,['dgfh blu','False'],['black','True']]

df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data_2, columns=[['colors','is it']])
print(df_2)




['red', 'black', 'white', "a'pink", 'blue']
my data frame is: 
          colors
0         on red
1   aup red gone
2  black with bi
3     ao a' pink
4       dgfh blu
5    a black pen
##############################
i need the answer be but i dont know how put regex for strings from list: 
     colors  is it
0       red   True
1       red   True
2     black   True
3   a' pink   True
4  dgfh blu  False
5     black   True
end
```

Comment: You could iterate through your list of colors (if it isn't too large) and for each use method `str.contains` to check in which rows the color is contained and modify these rows accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function to check if the DF value contains any of the strings and if so change the colors column. Note code below loses the spacee in `a' pink` to produce required result. I am not sure if this more broadly applies to your language structure.

```
import pandas as pd

color_list = ['red', 'black', 'white', "a'pink", 'blue']
pattern = '|'.join(color_list)

data = ['on red', 'aup red gone', 'black with bi', "ao a' pink", 'dgfh blu', 'a black pen']

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['colors'])

def func(row):
    for word in color_list:
    if word in row['colors'].replace("' ", "'"):
            row['is it'] = True
            row['colors'] = word
            break
    else:
        row['is it'] = False
    return row

df = df.apply(func, axis = 1)

print(df)
```

which gives:

```
     colors  is it
0       red   True
1       red   True
2     black   True
3    a'pink   True
4  dgfh blu  False
5     black   True
```

Comment: in the Greek language it is used very often.
When the letter follows (') it means a number
(Α' περίοδος) == (1st period)
(B' επίπεδο) == (2st Level )
and i need to give True
Thank you !!!

Comment: how replace "on red" with "red" from color_list?

Comment: Code edited to deal with the 2 comments above. I am not sure if the replace method more broadly applies to other Greek language structures you might also want to use but the answer gives you a basis to work on.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to incorporate a dictionary `D={ }`.

For illustrative purposes:

```
>>>
>>> import re
>>>
>>> D = {}
>>> D['red'] = 'True'
>>> D['black'] = 'True'
>>> D["a' pink"] = 'True'
>>> D['dgfh blu'] = 'False'
>>>
>>> column = '''
...          on red
...    aup red gone
...   black with bi
...      ao a' pink
...        dgfh blu
...     a black pen
... '''
>>>
>>> def repl(m):
...   return m.group(1)+"  "+D[m.group(1)]
...
>>> column = re.sub(r"(?m)^.*?(red|black|a'[ ]pink|dgfh[ ]blu)\b.*?$",repl,column)
>>>
>>> print(column)

red  True
red  True
black  True
a' pink  True
dgfh blu  False
black  True

>>>
```

Comment: This does not operate on the OP's DataFrame nor use the color_list. Also bizarrely the defined dictionary assumes the answers by inspection `D['dgfh blu'] = 'False'` without any sort of coded test. The output is not two columns as required by the OP. How do you consider this an answer to the question raised?